# PyCharm 2018 for Mac - there is no terminal option at all

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pycharm

recently installed PyCharm edu 2018 and there is no Terminal option at all. There is Python console in View/Tool Windows as well as Event Log etc. But no terminal.

My MacBook had Python 2.7 by default, i also installed 3.7 and then installed pycharm. OS 10.13.1

There is no Terminal in PyCharm/Preferences as well. Any way to get it? Is there any difference between EDU edition and community edition?

In Windows, Community edition 2018 is having the terminal option.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: When you say no Terminal in the Preferences, Have you checked Tools -> Terminal?
You should have the terminal:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/working-with-system-console.html?keymap=secondary_mac_os_x

Comment: no it is not there. I checked that website and PyCharm before posting. Very puzzling.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct PyCharm Edu does not have a terminal in Windows either. Only PyCharm Community has a terminal option. I did a lot of research and did not find any option to get a terminal for Edu.

Comment: seems this is the case. I will try to find Community edition, my first attempts were not successful; the links point to the professional one.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=mac select the right Download button for community edition.

Answer (score 0):

In the top menu bar, go to

`View -> Tool Windows -> Terminal` or on enter `Alt + F12`

Comment: It doesn't exist there as well. It's puzzling. Only other options, other than Terminal.

Comment: Maybe try a reinstalling PyCharm